# "Redirect" to a FormData object

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to simulate a form submit with the values stored in a form data object. I can't use a classic form because I need to include dynamically created file object.

How can I simulate a POST form submit with the values of the FormData object?

i.e. The data should be sent in an HTTP request and the HTTP response should be used to show a new page, just as if the user had loaded a new page by submitting a form.

Answer (score 3):

just initialize a FormData object and fill it with your params and then do the ajax call

```
let input = 'hello';
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('input', input);
// append the data you need

$.ajax({
    url: yoururl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: What if i don't want to make an ajax request ? I would like to simulate a form submit.

Comment: A form submit is almost the same as an ajax request the only diffrence is the redirect to a new page whats missing with ajax. You could also do a xhr request.

Comment: I know that it's almost same, but for some reason I have no control on the target page, so that's why I can't use an ajax or an xhr request.

Comment: How about create input fields filled with your data and submit trigger the submit afterwards?

Comment: You can't set the value of a file input for security reasons, that's why I can't use a classic form.

Comment: oh yes didn´t thought about that. But i still don´t get the point whats the problem with your target site. I guess you should be a bit more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The OP needs to use Ajax and then change `window.location` to the page they want it to go to